# Why doesn't ng-view render my templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I stuck with the integration of the ui-router into my angular app.
To keep it simple, it works, only the template does not get rendered.
I also don't get any errors.

*html layout file*

```
div.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li
      a(ui-sref='index') Home
    li
      a(ui-sref='about') About

div.container
  div.view-frame(ui-view)
```

*Partials for Home (about looks similar)*

```
div.row(ng-controller='HomeCtrl')
  div.col-sm-12
    h1.lead Welcome
```

*My routes*

```
$stateProvider
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about/',
    templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'
    //template: '<h1>Test</h1>' doesn't work as well
  })
 .state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/partials/index.html'
  })
```

When I click on one of these link and check my network traffic, the templates/partial get loaded also the url changes.
I even can see the right preview of my html in the chrome developer tool.
My only problem is, that the ui router does load it into the ui-view directive.

I use the latest Chrome and the latest version of ui-router.
I load all my partials via api, but that should matter anyway.
I used the normal route provider before and that one worked just fine, I try to 'upgrade'.

Am I doing something wrong or did I discover a bug here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you are using jade.  Leaving off the value of an attribute makes the value the as the attributes name, thus your generated/rendered HTML looks like

```
<div class="view-frame" ui-view="ui-view"></div>
```

When ui-router looks for a view in your state called `'ui-view'`, it cannot find it. When it looks for a view in your template called `''`, it cannot find it.  You need to set your attribute to an empty string so ui-router can find the default of `''`

```
div.view-frame(ui-view='')
```

Comment: Oh dear, I hate myself not seeing the tree in the forest. Thanks for solving.......